# How to compile and run a JSP Beans project using Eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

I am a noob trying to learn what I can about JSPs. I am using Eclipse as my ide and have run into a small problem that I hope someone can help me out with. I have a dynamic web project with the following files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Get Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="saveName.jsp" method="post">
        What is your name?
        <input type="text" name="username" size="20">
        <br> 
        What is your email address?
        <input type="text" name="email" size="20">
        <br>
        What is your age?
        <input type="text" name="age" size="4">
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

nextPage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="user.UserData" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Next Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    You entered
    <br>
    Name: <%=user.getUserName()%>
    <br>
    Email: <%=user.getUserEmail()%>
    <br>
    Age: <%=user.getUserAge()%>
</body>
</html>
```

saveName.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="user.UserData" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="user" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Save Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="nextPage.jsp">Continue</a>
</body>
</html>
```

userData.java

```
package user;

public class UserData {

    String userName;
    String userEmail;
    String userAge;

    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param userName
     *            the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userEmail
     */
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @param userEmail
     *            the userEmail to set
     */
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userAge
     */
    public String getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }

    /**
     * @param userAge
     *            the userAge to set
     */
    public void setUserAge(String userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }

}
```

This app runs just fine except that my nextPage.jsp has null for all of the values. I know this is is because the userData.java is not being called.

Here is how the project is set up the html and jsp files are in the WebContent folder. userData.java is in the Java Resources folder under the user package. I am pretty sure the class for userData is supposed to be copied into the WEB-INF folder but it is not and even if I place it there myself the project still does not run right. Can someone show me how to set this up in Eclipse so that it will run correctly and I can experiment more with JSPs.

Comment: You code is seems fine. then what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the difference between you input name and the setter of `UserData`, please try to modify the `index.html` as:

```
<form action="saveName.jsp" method="post">
    What is your name?
    <input type="text" name="userName" size="20">
    <br> 
    What is your email address?
    <input type="text" name="userEmail" size="20">
    <br>
    What is your age?
    <input type="text" name="userAge" size="4">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have test it OK. Wish it helps.

Comment: Thank you. That worked and now looking at my code I understand why it does. Thanks again

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept my answer if you find it useful.